# How to sed stuff within pairs of quotes?

Tags: sed

I want to change lines like:

```
<A HREF="classes_index_additions.html"class="hiddenlink">
```

to

```
<A HREF="classes_index_additions.html" class="hiddenlink">
```

(note the added ' ' before `class`) but it should leave lines like

```
<meta name="generator" content="JDiff v1.1.1">
```

alone. `sed -e 's|\("[^"]*"\)\([^ />]\)|\1 \2|g'` satisfies the first condition but it changes the other text to

```
<meta name="generator" content=" JDiff v1.1.1"/>
```

How do I get `sed` to process the correct pairs of double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`sed -e 's/"\([^" ]*\)=/" \1=/g'`

But with sed, it may be possible that the regular expression matches other parts of your document that you didn't intend, so best to try it and look over the results to see if there are any unintended side effects!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that there can be any number of attributes in the nodes.

Comment: If there are more than two attributes all stuck together, do they look like this:

`<A HREF="classes_index_additions.html"class="hiddenlink"property="value">`

Comment: Sometimes they're stuck together; sometimes they're not. I want to fix the ones that are stuck together and leave alone the ones that aren't.

Comment: OK, see my edits above, it's simpler but it could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting each attributes on a new line and then triming trailing spaces on each line before removing new lines.

```
sed -r 's/(\w*="[^"]*")/\n\1/g; s/ *\n/\n/g; s/\n/ /g'
```

This works as follow :

```
s/(\w*="[^"]*")/\n\1/g
```

Put every attributes on a new line so your node looks like this

```
<A 
HREF="classes_index_additions.html"
class="hiddenlink">
```

After that you remove trailing spaces

```
s/ *\n/\n/g
```

And remove new lines

```
s/\n/ /g
```